# What do these symbols mean in the report?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I sometimes wonder what the marked symbols mean when I'm looking on a report of a Pokémon. Some of them imply a direct meaning, but I'd rather be sure.

**What do these symbols mean and are some of them essential for online competition?**

[image: Screenshot with questioned symbols marked. German localization]
*Sample with questioned symbols marked. German localization.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those symbols are set only by players and is completely up to the player.

There are coincidentally 6 marks (equal to the number of stats: HP, Atk, Def, Sp.Atk, Sp.Def, Spd) you can 'mark' or un-'mark', which can be ideal to mark what stats of a Pokemon are at 31 IVs, which I've found to be the most common use of these.

Of course, it's entirely up to you to decide what to do with them.

You can 'mark' or un-'mark' from the summary page of a Pokemon or through the 'Marking' option in your PC box.

Comment: Marking for "Full IVs" is definitely the community standard, however I tend to mark with "Wanted IVs", which has a small but subtle difference: example, Say I'm breeding for a Golurk with a 0 IV Speed Stat to increase the power of Gyro Ball, or for use on a Trick Room team. If I had one with 0 Speed, I would 'mark' that so that I know it has the Speed stat that *I want*. (Obviously I remove this when trading away imperfect offspring).

Comment: and that pink mark? i traded one that had a pink mark next to the blue one and another with a green one. i know the red one is to mark shiny. I really dont know what those extra marks mean.

Comment: @Visigodo666 Can you get a picture? I didn't come across such marks, but I might have seen similar ones in previous versions.

Comment: Pink could be pokerus for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The pink smiley means that the Pokemon has Pokerus but it is unable to pass it along anymore, if it says Pokerus, it can still pass it to other Pokemon.

Answer (score -3):

The blue pentagon signifies it is a certified pokemon and not brought in via cheating

Comment: This is not right. The blue pentagon means that that the pokemon was obtained ingame. It hasn't been certified or something. There are still hacks out there which modify the encounter itself. So it's possible to catch a lvl  1 rayquaza in the wild and it got the blue pentagon. Only Pokemon which got it origins in Gen 6 have it, pokemon from generations before 6 don't have the pentagon.

Answer (score -3):

I think the pink smiley means it's at max friendship

Comment: No, it's not. It means that the Pokemon was infected with Pokerus.